# How to update perl module with cpanm

Tags: perl, module, updates, cpan, cpanm

I try to install/update Perl module with cpanm. But, it failed for every modules.

for example:

```
cpanm Config::General
--> Working on Config::General
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/T/TL/TLINDEN/Config-General-2.56.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring Config-General-2.56 ... OK
Building and testing Config-General-2.56 ... OK
Successfully installed Config-General-2.56 (upgraded from 2.52)
1 distribution installed
```

So, i expect that version of Config::General is now 2.56, but... :

```
perl -e 'use Config::General 2.56'
Config::General version 2.56 required--this is only version 2.52 at -e line 1.
```

I try the same logged in superU but same problem... 
But now, i have Perl lib in

`~/perl5/lib/perl5/` and `/usr/lib/perl/5.18/`

How can i properly update Perl modules with `cpanm`?

---

Some information about my install:

```
$ perl -E'
   say "$_=$ENV{$_}" for qw( PERL_MM_OPT PERL_MB_OPT PERL5LIB );
   say "--";
   say for @INC;
'
PERL_MM_OPT=INSTALL_BASE=/home/hacklionex/perl5
PERL_MB_OPT=--install_base "/home/hacklionex/perl5"
PERL5LIB=
--
/etc/perl
/usr/local/lib/perl/5.18.2
/usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2
/usr/lib/perl5
/usr/share/perl5
/usr/lib/perl/5.18
/usr/share/perl/5.18
/usr/local/lib/site_perl
.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your are instructing the module installers to install modules in `/home/hacklionex/perl5` (via `PERL_MM_OPT` and `PERL_MB_OPT`), but you don't tell Perl to look for modules there (it's not in `@INC`). Add the following to your login script:

```
export PERL5LIB=/home/hacklionex/perl5/lib/perl5
```

Or add the following to your script:

```
use lib '/home/hacklionex/perl5/lib/perl5';
```

Comment: it works now, thanks a lot. Some modules Failed to update because of permission access. I have one more question: how do I know where cpanm install the module, in the case where I am logged in SuperU or not?

Comment: `cpanm` doens't install any modules. It runs the distro's `Makefile.PL` or `Build.PL`. `Makefile.PL` is expected to use ExtUtils::MakeMaker to install the distro, and `Build.PL` is expected to use Module::Build. Both take options from the command line which can also be specified in environment variables (`PERL_MM_OPT` and `PERL_MB_OPT` respectively).